# SSL Certificate SAN or Wildcard?

Tags: ssl, certificate, wildcard

I'm wanting to cover the a few domains with an SSL Certificate. 
e.g.

- portal.domain.com
- app.domain.com
- app1.domain.com
- app2.domain.com

I'm a bit confused as to whether I can go for the cheaper Unified Communications Certificate, or whether I need to fork out for a wildcard certificate.
Is the only difference that the wildcard can have an unlimited number of subdomains, where the UCC only covers a set number under the SANs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right Unified Communications Certificate covers a set on SANs but it can secure multiple domains, and hosts configured in your Exchange server where a traditional wildcard SSL cannot. For e.g. A wildcard ssl can secure first level of sub-domains like *.example dot com where a Unified Communications Certificate secures www.example dot com, www.example dot net etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Keep in mind that some old X.509 implementations might not support SAN, but that's pretty rare today (some Symbian OS phones for example, see http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name-compatibility.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a domain name or URL requires just one certificate to be secure. But what if you need to secure multiple domains? How can you manage their security without sacrificing budget and time?

Securing Multiple Domains

Securing multiple domains can be achieved with 2 approaches, Wildcard certificates and Unified Communications Certificates (UCC), also known as SAN (Subject Alternative Name). SAN lets you specify additional host names (sites, IP addresses, common names, etc.) to be protected by a single SSL Certificate, while a Wildcard certificate can support a single domain and an unlimited number of first-level subdomains. SAN/UCC can also be combined as an extension with a Wildcard to add functionality to the certificate. You can combine these two certificates as a Multi-domain Wildcard SSL Certificate depending on your needs. This makes managing the security of multiple websites much easier and cheaper than managing a separate SSL certificate for every domain you own.

Read More: [**Wildcard Vs SAN/UCC Certificates**](http://ssladvice.com/securing-multiple-domains-with-sanucc-certificates/)

Answer (score 0):

It's only cheaper up until a certain number of domains, because UC and SAN certs charge by each domain name. You'll notice the price changes as you enter and subtract domains from this [UCC link](http://www.ssl.com/certificates/ucc/buy)

If you know that you will have more than say 5 subdomains, save some cash with the wildcard because it's a set prices regardless of the number of sub domains.

Answer (score 0):

UCC and SAN is only recommended for exchange server. your requirement seems like you need ssl with common name *.domain.com so that single ssl works for all sub-domains.

Know what exactly UCC and SAN is..
UCC / SAN cert is recommended only if you need to secure different tld like urdomain.com urdomain.co.uk urmydomain.net. This kind certs cost too much as it starts from $200.

Answering your question, I checked few brands wildcard ssl RapidSSL wildcard, comodo positive ssl wildcard, globalsign alphassl wildcard, geotrust wildcard ssl. I tested these brands installed ssl website in my iPhone and Samsung android phone. All works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed many ssl providers for UC certificates pricing. Apart from the pricing, I found some ssl providers sell same product with different names, like multi-domains ssl, san certificate and uc certificates.

Microsoft exchange server requires typical UC certificate, strongly recommended by Microsoft. I decided to purchase UC certificate but it costs too much, starts from $300 to $600 with veriour providers like comodo, globalsign, digicerts etc. First I purchase single domain ssl and failed in exchange server installation. I thought could save $$$ with single domain ssl.

Later I searched for UC certificate prices $50 to $100 and found ssl2buy ssl company provides comodo uc certificates for $60 only and it includes 4 domains.

https://www.ssl2buy.com/comodo-multi-domain-ssl.php

I purchased this uc certificate and installed on my exchange server. It works fine! No error - No installation issue, nothing.